# Taking element from spinner to listview on click and selectable(android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-spinner

so im a beginner in android programming and I want to do this but I dont know how; basically, I have a spinner; I want to make the element from the spinner go to a listview only **when I click a button** , and also be able to add more than 1 element to this listview, and also be able to select an item from the listview. I dont know how to do that.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I see no particular issue here. You might just need to figure out how everything fits together.

Assume you have your list view with defined layout.

Next, you need a list adapter like:

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_list_layout, parent, false);
        }

       // the rest...
    }
}
```

or if your list is simple enough:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view, list);
```

Implement OnClick listener to your button where you:

- Call additem method on the adapter passing your value form spinner.
- Or add multiple items

If you want item from the list to be selected you can create onItemClickListener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // do stuff here
            }
        });
```

Hopefully that will help